# Handling encode() when converting from python2 to python3

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode

I'm working on converting a large project from `python2` to `python3` (not requiring `python2` backwards compatibility).

When testing the conversion, I found I was having an issue where certain strings were being converted to `bytes` objects, which was causing trouble. I traced it back to the following method, which gets called in a number of places:

```
def custom_format(val):
    return val.encode('utf8').strip().upper()
```

In `python2`:

```
custom_format(u'\xa0')
# '\xc2\xa0'
custom_format('bar')
# `BAR`
```

In `python3`:

```
custom_format('\xa0')
# b'\xc2\xa0'
custom_format('bar')
# b`BAR`
```

The reason this is an issue is because at some points the output of `custom_format` is meant to be inserted into a `SQL` template string using `format()`, but `'foo = {}'.format(b'bar') == "foo = b'BAR'"`, which would mess up potential the `SQL` syntax.

Simply removing the `encode('utf8')` part would ensure that `custom_format('bar')` properly returns `'BAR'`, but now `custom_format('\xa0')` returns `'\xa0'` rather than the `'\xc2\xa0'` of the `python2` version. (though I don't know enough about unicode to know if that's a bad thing or not)

Without messing with the `SQL` or `format()` parts of the code, how can I make sure the expected behavior from the `python2` version is exhibited in the `python3` version? Is it as simple as dropping `encode('utf8')` or will that cause unintended conflicts?

Comment: When I removed encode and used the function on '\xa0' in py3, it returned '' instead of '\xa0'.

Comment: Not sure if that's best solution: `str(val.encode('utf8').strip().upper())[2:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to ensure all incoming strings, be it `str`s or `bytes`, get converted into `bytes`, then you have to keep `encode` since Python3 uses `str` instead of `bytes` (which is the case for Python2) as the native string type. `encode` converts `str` into `bytes`.

If your intent is to ensure that the queries look right. Then you can just remove `encode` and let Python3 handle things for you.